# How to use different counters / tablenames for table and longtable?

Tags: longtable

**What I want**:

Table 1: table content …
LongTable 1: longtable content …

**What I get:**

Table 1: table content …
Table 2: longtable content....

example:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{this is table environment}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{longtable}{||l|c||}
        \caption{this is longtable environment}
        \endfirsthead
        content & 12 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Maybe `ctex` is not concerned with the issue and should be deleted in the MWE. And what I get from the MWE (after deleting the `ctex` package) is different from your description. Maybe you can consider editing your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry I deleted `ctex` package, and added the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `\listofLTs` to work, I had to modify longtable slightly.  It was then easier to use the new counter than swap them back and forth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[% counter name is LT
    listname=List of Long Tables,
    name={Long Table},
    fileext=lolt
]{LT}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@LT{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lolt}{LT}{\protect\numberline{\theLT}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\patchcmd{\LT@array}{\refstepcounter{table}}{\refstepcounter{LT}}{}{FAILED}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \listoftables
  \listofLTs
  
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{this is table environment}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{longtable}{||l|c||}
        \caption{this is longtable environment}
        \endfirsthead
        content & 12 \\
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

---

If you load the caption package, a much simpler solution is possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}% required
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[% counter name is LT
    listname=List of Long Tables,
    name={Long Table},
    fileext=lolt
]{LT}
\renewcommand{\LTcaptype}{LT}

\begin{document}
  \listoftables
  \listofLTs
  
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \caption{this is table environment}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{longtable}{||l|c||}
        \caption{this is longtable environment}
        \endfirsthead
        content & 12 \\
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the long table acts the same with table in terms of caption, so you need to make some adjustments.

#### Situation 1: Use the same counter

Just use the `caption` package to change the name of long table, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{name={Long Table}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{this is table environment}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{longtable}{||l|c||}
        \caption{this is longtable environment}
        \endfirsthead
        content & 12 \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image: Way 1]

#### Situation 2: Use a different counter (a new type of float)

Use the `newfloat` package and `DeclareFloatingEnvironment` your desired environment.
Here is the code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    listname=List of Long Tables,
    name=LongTable,
    placement=tbhp
]{LT}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{this is table environment}
        \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
            1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{LT}
        \caption{this is longtable environment}
        \begin{longtable}[H]{||l|c||}
            \endfirsthead
            content & 12 \\
        \end{longtable}
    \end{LT}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result 2]

Comment: Thx, it works. Furthermore, how can I get current tablename and counter in `LT` environment? such as `\tablename \thetable` in `table` environment.

Comment: In other words, when the longtable across pages in **Situation 2**, how can I keep the same `tablename` and `counter` on subsequent pages

Comment: If LT is a float, you can't have one longer than one page.  What you can do is swap out counters each time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Could you tell me in detail？